# Is it possible to move an VM virtual box running Linux Mint that is encrypted to a physical laptop with a HD bigger than the image?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-mint

my computer is on Windows 10 running VM virtual box 6.1. I had installed Linux Mint on one of the VM but I had it encrypted during installation.  Is it possible to copy this to VM and install it on a physical laptop?  What would happen to the encryption? especially when the the laptop has a bigger drive on an SSD?
thank you.

Comment: Do you want encryption on new PC? Is it UEFI or bios? For sure you can copy it, using rsync for example - see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Rsync#Full_system_backup as long as destination filesystem is correctly defined. For more details see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Migrate_installation_to_new_hardware#File_copying It doesn't matter if source is a VM or a physical PC.

Comment: @lx07 thats really interesting so will rsync clone everything including my login.  I do want to encrypt on the pc. Can I do it post? thank you.

Comment: You can. I moved VBox VM to my ThinkPad using those links. The only thing you need to do is mount the Pc's SSD from the VM, create and format the partitions and copy it. You can choose to make an encrypted partition to copy to. Then sort the bootloader and you are done. Your login, password etc are copied. Check the arch wiki for encryption details- I find it the clearest description : https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system